# `Series` gives wrong result

Tags: simplifying-expressions, bugs, symbolic, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

The following code shows that `Series` gives different results depending on whether one simplifies the expression in the first place. Let's assume all variables real.

```
f = (4 x^2)/((-a^2 - 4 x^2 + a Sqrt[a^2 + 4 x^2]) (a^2 + 4 x^2 + 
     a Sqrt[a^2 + 4 x^2]));
Series[Simplify[f], {x, 0, 1}]
(*-(1/a^2)+O[x]^2*)
Series[f, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
(*O[x]^2*)
```

Comment: The command Series[f, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a \ [Element] Reals] produces -(1/a^2)+O[x]^2.

Comment: I wouldn't blame `Series`. Compare `f /. x -> 0` and `Simplify[f] /. x -> 0`.

Comment: OK, maybe you should blame `Series`: `Limit[f, x -> 0]` and `Limit[Simplify[f], x -> 0]` both give `-1/a^2`.

Comment: @user64494 Not working with my V12 MMA. What version are you using?

Comment: With v12, I have to do this: Series[Simplify[f], {x, 0, 1}] and then I get the same as @user64494.  Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: With version 11, `Series[f, {x, 0, 2}]` gives `(4 x^2)/(a^2 (-a+Sqrt[a^2]) (a+Sqrt[a^2]))+O[x]^3` which is even more questionable: denominator is zero for any `a`

Comment: Confirmed bug present in 10.0

Comment: @xiaohuamao 你是中国哪里的人呢 看你的名字是中文名 有点好奇

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple workaround:

```
ClearAll[a, x]; f = (4 x^2)/((-a^2 - 4 x^2 + 
  a Sqrt[a^2 + 4 x^2]) (a^2 + 4 x^2 + a Sqrt[a^2 + 4 x^2]));
Series[f, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Re[a] > 0]
*-(1/a^2)+O[x]^2 *
Series[f, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Re[a] < 0]
 *-(1/a^2)+O[x]^2 *
```

The case $\Re a=0$ makes a trouble.

Comment: For me (in version 11) `Assumptions -> Re[a] != 0` also gives wrong answer

Comment: The same in version 12.0. However, both assumptions Assumptions -> Re[a] > 0 and Assumptions -> Re[a] <0 work separately.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the expression You like to evolve into the series first:

[image]

Then reduce by hand the nominator, denominator. The expression in the first argument of Series is than more simply:

[image]

Nice equivalent for math thinking is using Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

So Your question addresses plenty of complexity in Mathematica. Advice is:

Keep in mind Mathematica calculates solutions on an algorithmics process path.
It went where You ask it to go.
Wolfram Alpha takes over some more intelligence or better experience. Because it shows up plenty of standard solution You might expect to be of importance for You.
Use visualizations as often as possible.
A general rule and a rule from Wolfram Alpha is asking Mathematica to do the calculation as simple as possible.
Think on the domains and deal with them logically. (Example: Neither the Assumption a==0 nor a>0&&a<0 cause other than evaluation warnings and logical confusion. Nor does a!=0 is a better logic.)

The Wolfram Alpha solution and my more specific do not make use of `Assumptions`.

The most important paradigma for Mathematics is stay lazy is best or even optimum. Always wonder and aks.